# How to perform only one DB update for default user session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I try to figure out how default session work in asp.net.
**I need to create one log for every guest visiting my website** (in the log i store location, date etc.).

I thought that i can do that during user session.

does any body have idea how to do that ?

Comment: For the real users `if(Session["OneTime"] != "1") {logMe();Session["OneTime"]="1"}` For the bots that not keep the session on each call you need to find some other way

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Session_OnStart event in the global.asax file, but that will only indicate new sessions and each unique users.

It's described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178583.aspx) on MSDN.